Embedded JSON object to Typescript interface
I have JSON string like this:
{
  "root": {
    "park": [
      {
        "DateTime": [
          "2024-0822T20:34:46"
        ],
        "Name": [
          "0"
        ],
        "Status": [
          "Open"
        ],
        "Free": [
          "523"
        ],
        "Total": [
          "596"
        ],
        "Present": [
          "73"
        ]
      },
      {
        "DateTime": [
          "2024-0822T20:34:46"
        ],
        "Name": [
          "1"
        ],
        "Status": [
          "Open"
        ],
        "Free": [
          "151"
        ],
        "Total": [
          "200"
        ],
        "Present": [
          "49"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Trying to figure out how to define it as Typescript interface, but casting the JSON to interface I've already defined:
export interface Root {
    root: Root2
  }
  
  export interface Root2 {
    park: Park[]
  }
  
  export interface Park {
    DateTime: string[]
    Name: string[]
    Status: string[]
    Free: string[]
    Total: string[]
    Present: string[]
  }


returns just undefined.
The function handling the XML conversion is like this:
    try {
        xml2js.parseString(xmlString, {trim: true}, (error, result) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
                return undefined;
            } else {
               console.log('JSON: ' + JSON.stringify(result)); 
               return result as Root;     
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return undefined;
    }
}

So how are the interfaces not matching the data? return result as Root is always undefined. Examples are welcome.

You've got root as the top level property in your JSON, not park

Welcome to Stack Overflow. • What exactly "results in undefined"? Where? Could you show us a [mre] that demonstrates this? • It is quite unlikely that you want single-element tuple types like [string] (those aren't all that useful in general). Is that just a confusion for string[]? Or are you really trying to say that all your arrays always have exactly one element?

In the JSON Name, Free, Total, Present are all strings, not numbers.

Already noticed that numbers are actually strings. Changed that but no effect.

It's also missing Status.

No effect where? Please [edit] to show what you mean. If I debug your code to something like this, then I get no errors, but I really have no idea what "undefined" you're talking about. Right now there aren't enough debugging details to answer this and it risks being closed as such.

And the JSON is bad as its originally invalid XML that is mapped to JSON using xml2js.

So this is about xml2js then? Then that's what you're asking about and it has nothing to do with TypeScript interfaces? I'm more confused than before. What's xmlString? Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can use to see what you're seeing.

@jcalz it is and its not. Xml2js produces that JSON string. So I'm asking how to map the JSON string to typescript interface.

Also added new examples of the interfaces I'm using now. The mapping should work with those but still getting undefined in return result as Root.

Either it's about xml2js in which case we need the xmlString directly, or it's not, and we don't need to see xml2js.parseString in the question. Either way, the issue with undefined has absolutely nothing to do with TypeScript interfaces. Something bad is happening at runtime, but you haven't given us enough to reproduce your problem: I don't see undefined happening anywhere in my IDE. This is not a [mre]. You have a bunch of console.log() in there; what gets logged?

I'm confused as to how interfaces "return" undefined. Interfaces don't return anything
